# GAE Python: Parsing compressed XML exceeds memory

Tags: python, xml, google-app-engine, gzip

I am trying to fetch and parse an XML file into a databse. The XML is compressed in GZIP. The GZIP file is ~8MB. When I run the code locally the memory on pythonw.exe builds up to level where the entire system (Windows 7) stops responding, and when I run it online it exceeds the memory limit on Google App Engine. Not sure if the file is too big or if I am doing something wrong. Any help would be very much appreciated!

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.api.urlfetch import fetch
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
import gzip
import base64
import StringIO

class ParseCatalog(webapp.RequestHandler):
user = xxx
password = yyy
catalog = fetch('url',
                    headers={"Authorization": 
                             "Basic %s" % base64.b64encode(user + ':' + password)}, deadline=600)
xmlstring = StringIO.StringIO(catalog.content)
gz = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=xmlstring)
gzcontent = gz.read()
contentxml = parseString(gzcontent)
items = contentxml.getElementsByTagName("Product")

for item in items:
    item = DatabaseEntry()
    item.name = str(coupon.getElementsByTagName("Manufacturer")[0].firstChild.data)
    item.put()
```

***UPDATE***

So I tried to follow BasicWolf's suggestion to switch to LXML but am having problems importing it. I downloaded the LXML 2.3 library and put it in the folder of my app (I know this is not ideal, but it's the only way I know how to include a 3rd party library). Also, I added following to my app.yaml:

```
libraries:
- name: lxml
  version: "2.3"
```

Then I wrote the following code to test if it parses:

```
import lxml

class ParseCatalog(webapp.RequestHandler):
    user = xxx
    password = yyy
    catalog = fetch('url',
                    headers={"Authorization": 
                             "Basic %s" % base64.b64encode(user + ':' + password)}, deadline=600)
    items = etree.iterparse(catalog.content)

    def get(self): 
       for elem in items:
           self.response.out.write(str(elem.tag))
```

However this is resulting in the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name etree
```

I have checked other questions on this error and it seems that the fact that I run on Windows 7 might play a role. I also tried to install the pre-compiled binary packages from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml but that didn't change anything either.

Comment: What do you mean by "my system crashes"?

Comment: The memory use of pythonw.exe keeps building up making the system unresponsive for anything I try to do. (Running on Windows 7)

Comment: `gz.read()` puts the entire file in memory.  Do you know how big the file is uncompressed?

Comment: @Mark: The file is 80MB uncompressed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you expect? First, you read a string into the memory, then - unzip it into the memory, then - construct a DOM tree, still in the memory.

Here are some improvements:

1. `del` every buffer variable the moment you don't need it.
2. Get rid of DOM XML parser, use event-driven LXML to save memory.

Comment: I figured the problem was somewhere around this. I also tried e.g. to parse the file as a whole but couldn't get that working. I'm going to try to get it working on LXML then.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't get LXML to work so far. I've updated the information in the question.

Comment: @Vincent, lxml is supported by GAE if you use Python 2.7, see https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27?hl=en What you simpy have to do: `from lxml import etree`, see http://lxml.de/tutorial.html

Comment: Thanks BasicWolf. I must have done something wrong in the migration to Python2.7. I redid it and tried again, and now I don't have the memory issue anymore.